# ios 7.1 Add songs to Music Library

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

With Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1, Now you can access music library from Simulator,

[image]

I just need to know how to add songs to simulator music library.

Thanks.

Comment: selecting an mp3 from your computer and drag an drop on simulator didn't work?

Comment: No sir, that didn't work

Comment: Previously, you could only add songs to the music library via iTunes. Did they change this with iOS 7?

Comment: @SarimSidd Did you get answer for his??

Comment: @MohitPopat No, This is still not allowed

Comment: Where are you seeing access to the music app on the simulator? I have both Xcode 5.1.1/iOS7.1 and the beta Xcode 6.0/iOS8.0 and there is no music app on either one.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. I want to add some music files into the library to test my app. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @user2889249 No, this is still not allowed. (You can not add media files to simulator).

Answer (score 0):

I research and... - no results.
So, my way is put audio file in project, take url and further use it for a work.

```
- (IBAction)loadAudio:(id)sender {
NSURL *audioUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                          pathForResource:@"audio"
                                                   ofType:@"mp3"]];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                         initWithContentURL:audioUrl];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
}
```

Also, perhaps this topic useful for you: [tap me](http://www.raywenderlich.com/69369/audio-tutorial-ios-playing-audio-programatically-2014-edition)

Comment: This does not add music to the simulator, which is what was asked.

Comment: man, no way add a music to a simulator and I propose my solution which work well for me. have a nice day.

Comment: If all you needed to do was access the file, then your solution would be the answer, but that's not what was needed.  Instead, he wants to populate the simulated music library.

Incidentally, that's also what I need to do, as I need to take screenshots from the simulator, showing the library populated.